# Assigning components to variables vs functions that return components

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a sub-component that I'm trying to render in react. I've been told (in passing) that I should prefer:

```
someComponent = () => <div />
```

over

```
someComponent = <div />
```

Are there performance or style implications that I would want one over the other?

Comment: Your second example is actually not a component, but will be compiled to `someComponent = React.createElement("div", null);`. The first example is a proper component.

Comment: In addition to @Tholle's explanation, the question is do you need a component functionality or not? If not you can use whatever you want I think.

Comment: As Tholle said, the first is better. You may conventionnaly name your component with an uppercase first letter.